# XAML ComboBox Bind to Property

Tags: xaml, binding

If I have a property in my C#;

```
    public CollectionView Months
    {
        get 
        {
            CollectionView retList = new Enumerations.Months().ToCollectionView<Enumerations.Months>();
            return retList;
        }
    }
```

And I have a ComboBox;

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ddlMonth" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Months}}"/>
```

How can I bind my ComboBox to my property?

I should add I'm a complete xaml newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, that isn't a method - it is a property.

All you have to do is this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ddlMonth" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Months}"/>
```

The trick is to ensure that whatever class the property `Months` appears in is set as the `DataContext` of the ComboBox or one of its parents (including the Page).

So if the `Months` property appears in the same page that hosts the ComboBox, then you can add this line of code in the constructor or `Loaded` event of the page:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

If the `Months` property appears in a ViewModel (which i hope it does!) then you need to assign the ViewModel to the `DataContext` of the page (or a subsidiary control that is still a parent (ancestor) of the ComboBox).

Comment: +1, Oops, yeah sorry not method, Property.  Editied question. thanks.